# Default nmap script execution when specifying --script banner

Tags: nmap

I have a subscription for an NMAP NSE scripts feed. There are some of those scripts which have the default category (among others)

I am running nmap in the following way

```
nmap --privileged -oX - -T3 -O --osscan-guess --max-os-tries=1 -sV -sS --script banner -PP -PE -PM -PI <ip_address>
```

However, what I am observing is that I am not getting only the output for the banner script, but for multiple other scripts which, as you can see, I am not requesting to be executed.

AFAIK, the scripts which are executed can be specified with the name or with the category (aside from the fact that the rules should return 'true'). In this case, I am specifying the name, so not sure why other scripts are also run.

Does anybody have any idea about the cause for this?

I have tried executing the scan with another instance in which i did not have the feed installed. In that case, I could see that the NMAP scripts which are provided with the default nmap installation are not executed unless I add them specifically as part of the command execution.

I really want the scripts not to execute unless I specifically tell nmap to do so.

Any idea?